# Magento2 Autoload error

Tags: magento2, autoloader

any solution for this error?

> createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class); * $bootstrap->run($app); * -------------------------------------------- * * Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details. */ try { require **DIR** . '/app/bootstrap.php'; } catch (\Exception $e) { echo <<
>   Autoload error
>   {$e->getMessage()}
>   HTML; exit(1); } $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER); /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */ $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class); $bootstrap->run($app);

Comment: Is it the full content of the error?

Comment: what does full content error mean?

Comment: The error you are getting, is all there or there is some other info you didn't include?

Comment: yes, this is the complete error. I did not exclude anything.

Comment: How did you get this error?

Comment: all the things was working fine. i installed phpmyadmin in ubuntu 18. then i removed the phpmyadmin. after removing i got this error. it think removing phpmyadmin removed any php module from system.

Comment: i am now installing the fresh Magento, but getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file is not processed like a PHP file but like a text file. So maybe you should look at your web server settings.

That one is not an error, but the content of the pub/index.php file.

Comment: thanks, @Luigi I solved this error. Actually my PHP mod was disabled so I enabled it by 
sudo a2enmod php7.2 then sudo service apache2 restart and now its working fine.

Comment: Great! Happy for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Seem PHP is not working properly on your server.